# Can I use a tactics under `coqtop -nois`?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

Just like op of [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837345/can-i-define-a-tactic-under-coqtop-nois), I am redeveloping `Coq.Init.Prelude` under `-nois` for pratice.
I want to use tactics, but they are no working.

I tried `Declare ML Module "ltac_plugin".` but it didn't help.

```
Welcome to Coq v8.8 (eccf1d50b020e87b4d19d0bda43361e1e82d01b1)

Coq < Declare ML Module "ltac_plugin".
[Loading ML file ltac_plugin.cmxs ... done]

Coq < Goal forall A:Prop, forall proof:A, A.
1 subgoal

  ============================
  forall (A : Prop) (_ : A), A

Unnamed_thm < intro.
Toplevel input, characters 0-5:
> intro.
> ^^^^^
Error: Syntax error: illegal begin of vernac.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to [`Set Default Proof Mode "Classic"`](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/981864d47efca1d42f43dc5b7c5439638a86f315/theories/Init/Notations.v#L126) to have access to the standard tactics. This option is currently [undocumented](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/6427).

```
$ rlwrap coqtop -nois
Welcome to Coq 8.8.0 (May 2018)

Coq < Declare ML Module "ltac_plugin".
[Loading ML file ltac_plugin.cmxs ... done]

Coq < Set Default Proof Mode "Classic".

Coq < Goal forall A:Prop, forall proof:A, A.
1 subgoal

  ============================
  forall (A : Prop) (_ : A), A

Unnamed_thm < intros.
1 subgoal

  A : Prop
  proof : A
  ============================
  A

Unnamed_thm < assumption.
No more subgoals.

Unnamed_thm < Qed.
Unnamed_thm is defined
```